# How is the relative speed of two (or more) objects determined (distributed) in the theoretical context of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, velocity, observers

Let's assume that observers on two moving objects, A and B, each determine, using doppler shift detection devices, that they are approaching each other at the rate of of $.5\,c$.

It's only natural to ask how much of this "total" speed difference is attributable to each object.  For example, is object A approaching the midpoint between them at the rate of $.1\,c$ and object B at the rate of $.4\,c\,$?  Are each approaching it at the rate of $.25\,c\,$?  Needless to say, there are an infinite number of possible combinations which could result in a gross difference of $.5\,c$.

So, using the Lorentz transforms in the context of special relativity theory, how is the difference in motion distributed between the two objects?  Where does the $.5\,c$, or some apportionate amount thereof, get "plugged in" to the formula?  Without having this information, any further calculation would seem to be impossible.  Given the tenets of SR, the answer would seem to be "we don't know that."  But not knowing doesn't alleviate the need to "somehow" attribute the motion, if one is to do any further calculations using the LT.

Edit:  More specifically if I, as observer A in this case, want to calculate whose clock has slowed down, where do I put the ".5c" when it comes to filling in "v" in the Lorentz tranformations?  Am I allowed to attribute it all to my own frame, implying that I, and I alone, am moving and that my clock has therefore slowed down, while attributing 0 motion to B, implying that he is at rest?   Is that an acceptable option?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132855/discussion-on-question-by-jack-how-is-the-relative-speed-of-two-or-more-object).

Answer (score 6):

> It's only natural to ask how much of this "total" speed difference is attributable to each object. For example, is object A approaching the midpoint between them at the rate of .1c and object B at the rate of .4c? Are each approaching it at the rate of .25c? Needless to say, there are an infinite number of possible combinations which could result in a gross difference of .5c.

These things just don't matter. From the perspective of both A and B, they are both stationary and the other is approaching them at $0.5c$. Or they could be moving towards the other at $0.5c$ and the other is stationary. The two perspectives just correspond to different reference frames, and the principle of relativity tells us that both are defensible, both are equally valid, and there is no "how much is attributable to each object".

Comment: I don't understand how such things could "not matter" if you're seeking answers to questions by using the LR.  Would it also be "equally valid" to say, if I am A, that I am moving toward the midpoint at the rate of .1c while B is approaching it at the rate of .4c?

Comment: @Jack not exactly because you need to use the relativistic addition of velocity formula (as opposed to the Galilean one which you're using), but aside from that, yes, it is "equally valid".

Comment: OK, so if I made that latter "equally valid" assumpton (.1c and .4c), where would I plug those two amounts into the LR formula?  Would I just offset the two amounts and say that the actual difference in the respective speeds is only .3c, not .5c?

Comment: @Jack what does LR stand for?

Comment: Sorry, for my mistake.  I actually meant to say "LT", not LR.  LT being an abbreviation for "Lorentz transformations?"

Comment: @Jack well you must choose a reference frame. If you choose the one where one object is moving at ~0.1c and the other is at ~0.4c, then that's the frame you'll have to use, although I don't see why would you want to use this reference frame. You'd have to transform twice, once with 0.1c and the other time with 0.4c. It's needlessly complicated.

Comment: Well, for me the problem is the assertion that all answers are "equally valid."  Assuming that all suppositions are "equally valid," it would seem to following that they are also equally invalid.  Any "choice" is strictly arbitrary with no rational or physical justification for the choice being made.

Comment: @Jack how does that make sense? A meter is equal to 100cm. It is also equal to 1000mm. Are you saying that because they are both correct, therefore they are both incorrect? I'm sorry, but that's just wrong; there is nothing more to say.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  Your "example," between two equivalent things, makes perfect sense.   Yes, in that case, Allure, both are correct.  But two antithetical answers cannot  "both" be correct.  It would make no sense, for example, to say that $1000 is equivalent to $10,000.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong coding in that comment, or something.  What I intended to say is that one thousand dollars is NOT equivalent to ten thousand dollars.  The amount of money I have in the bank is not determined by any arbitrary amount I "choose" to assign to it.  Of course 100 pennies equals one dollar, but that is irrelevant to the question being posed.

Comment: @Jack *two antithetical answers cannot "both" be correct* Note they don't lead to different predictions of physical phenomena. If this is your intuition, it is wrong.

Comment: Allure, "physical phenomena" is rather imprecise.  And I'm not even asking about "predictions" right now.  I can "predict" that if I have one thousand dollars in the bank and add a thousand, then I will then have two thousand.  Likewise, if I have ten thousand in the bank, I can "predict" that I will have eleven thousand if I add one thousand.  But if the question is "how much money do you have in the bank," the answers one thousand and ten thousand cannot be "equally valid."

Comment: @Jack no, that analogy breaks down because you have two different situations - 1000 in the bank and 10,000 in the bank. What we have here are two reference frames, one in which A is stationary and B is approaching at 50 m/s (we go to non-relativistic speeds here to simplify things), and the other where A is moving at 20 m/s and B is moving at 30 m/s. Can you name a physical observable where switching between these two reference frames actually yields different results?

Comment: Yes, I think I can...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132843/discussion-between-jack-and-allure).

Comment: Allure, click on the "continue this in chat" link, above, to see the example I came up with.

Comment: Allure, I responded to the suggestion you made in the chatroom, but it appears you left.  The response is still there, if you care to go back.

Answer (score 6):

> Needless to say, there are an infinite number of possible combinations which could result in a gross difference of .5c.

Yes, there are an infinite number of possible combinations, each one representing the situation in a different reference frame.

Note that this is not specifically related to special relativity. This is true also in Newtonian mechanics.

> For example, is object A approaching the midpoint between them at the rate of .1c and object B at the rate of .4c? Are each approaching it at the rate of .25c?

Note that these would be possible combinations in Newtonian mechanics, but neither of these are possible combinations in special relativity. To determine possible combinations in special relativity you would need to use the relativistic velocity addition formula. $$v’=\frac{u+v}{1+uv/c^2}$$ So for example, you could have each approach at a rate of $u=v=0.268 \ c$. Or one approach at $u=0.1 \ c$ and the other at $v=0.421 \ c$.

In any case, there is indeed an infinite number of possible combinations, each for a different frame. You choose which combination to use by selecting the frame. Any choice will do. This freedom to choose is the same in special relativity and Newtonian mechanics, with the only difference being the specific numbers.

Edit:

> Am I allowed to attribute it all to my own frame, implying that I, and I alone, am moving and that my clock has therefore slowed down, while attributing 0 motion to B, implying that he is at rest? Is that an acceptable option?

Yes. The principle of relativity states that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames. So you are free to use any inertial frame. That means that you can use the inertial frame where you are at rest (“your frame”) but you are free to use any other inertial frame if you prefer. The term “your frame” is just short hand for “the frame where you are at rest”, but you are free to use other frames as desired. The principle of relativity guarantees that if you do so then you can simply use the usual laws of physics and you will get correct answers. So A is free to use the frame where B is at rest and A is moving at 0.5 c.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132915/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-how-is-the-relative-speed-of-two-or-more-objects).

Answer (score 6):

This question is really just about the principle of relativity -- it's not specific to special relativity (SR). So we could equally well look at it in the context of Newtonian mechanics, which obeys Galilean relativity. Suppose two rockets A and B with the same mass are moving towards one another at 5 m/s. What will happen when they collide (assuming a perfectly elastic collision)? The answer is that they will end up moving apart at 5 m/s, and this is true regardless of whether you assume A is at rest, assume B is at rest, or use some other frame (e.g. one in which A moves at 4 m/s and B moves at -1 m/s). The physics is the same in every case.

The underlying fact is an important one -- the coordinates we use are just labels, and we can change the labels without changing the actual physics (the behavior of things). If you use feet per second instead of meters per second to do the calculations, the physical results are the same, you've just changed the units. Changing the reference frame is basically the same thing: instead of "meters per second relative to A" you're using "meters per second relative to B" or "relative to C". Nothing physical has changed, so you'll get the same results. This is the case both in Newtonian mechanics and in special relativity. The only complication in SR is that you have to use the Lorentz transform to "change units" between frames, instead of the Galilean transform.

Comment: I don't think Galilean relativity uses the same premises.  There, time is absolute and t always equals t'.   Onlthe other hand, SR incorporates the concept that "time" changes with velocity.  In order to know "how much" it has changed between two frames (using the LT) you have to assign a (relative) velocity to each.

Comment: By the way, Eric (and Marco) I left comments for each of you in the "chat rooms" that were established "automatically" for us.  Unfortunately I don't know of an easy way to find my way back to those "chat rooms."  Do you?

Comment: Hi Jack, no, only by looking at my history! I'm a bit useless as a user. But here is a link...https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132843/discussion-between-jack-and-allure

Comment: Nothing in your question here is specific to time -- you're asking about relativity of velocity, and velocity is just as relative for Galileo as it is for Einstein. And the end results are independent of which frame you choose in both cases, whether you use the Galilean transforms or the Lorentzian ones.

Comment: Eric, you say:  "Nothing in your question here is specific to time..."  By implication it is.  Relativity posits that time changes with velocity, and that t does NOT equal t' in different frames.  Neither Gallileo nor Newton had any notion that "time" changes from frame to frame.

Comment: Even in Newtonian physics the origin of the time may be different in different frames ($t \ne t'$ if $t$ is "Eastern Time" and $t'$ is "Pacific Time". It's just easier to do the conversion, i.e. the Galilean transform is simpler than the Lorentz transform. In both SR and Galilean relativity, the choice of coordinates is arbitrary and does not affect the underlying physics.

Answer (score 5):

The distance from New York to Los Angeles is 3000 miles.  It's only natural to ask how much of this "total" distance is attributable to each city. For example, is New York 1000 miles away and Los Angeles 2000 miles away?  Are they each 1500 miles away?  Needless to say, there are an infinite number of possible combinations which could result in a gross distance of 3000 miles.

So how is this distance distributed?   Given the tenets of geography, the answer would seem to be "we don't know that." But not knowing doesn't alleviate the need to "somehow" attribute the distance.

Does the above make sense to you?  If not, why not?  Your answer to that question is the answer to the question you posed.

Comment: Heh, Will, an amusing parody, to be sure.  But, I'm sorry, I can't see the analogy here.

Comment: @Jack:  Instead of stopping with "Heh", try explaining to yourself *exactly* why there is no need to decide how much of the distance is due to New York and how much to Los Angeles.  Then translate that explanation back to your original question, substituting speed for distance.  If you take the trouble to do this, it really will answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still now following you.  You must put some quantity in for speed if you plan to subject the data to a Lorentzian analysis.  The LT requires it.  And, in SR, the "formula" also supplies it.   ALL the motion is ALWAYS attributed to the "other guy."  Whether that is physically justified can still be asked, can't it?

Comment: Yes.  You must also put some quantity in for distance if you're driving from New York to California and want to calculate how much gas you'll need.  The formula for miles-per-gallon requires it.  And in the formula we use, if you're in New York, ALL of the distance is ALWAYS attributed to Los Angeles.  Do you think we need to ask whether that is "physically justified"?

Comment: LA and NY are NOT moving with respect to each other, so your "example" is not analogous.  Either way, I wouldn't say that I attribute the distance to LA.

Comment: If LA and NY were converging on each other, and if you wanted to calculate the amount of gas required to traverse the (every-changing) distance, you would want (need) to know if, at the moment you left, LA was coming toward you rather than you toward it.  Hell, if it's coming toward me, why even gas up?  It will be here soon enough.

Comment: Which brings to mind the old joke about the devout SR adherent on a train who asks the conductor:  "Does Chicago stop here?"

Answer (score 2):

Since A can not detect if it is  moving with constant velocity, neither can B except "relativ" to another object A or be can considered as the reference not moving object.
Only if both move to a third reference object , one can decide more.

Comment: Well, OK.  How is that done, then?  What "third object" is used to make the determination?

Comment: Any object that you care to choose.

Comment: @Jack I think you are not fully understanding the principle of relativity.   Keep in mind that there is no absolute frame of reference against which velocities can be measured. So there is no meaning to the question "how are the velocities distributed".  The fact that you ask this question is evidence of this!  You are looking for an absolute frame of reference, but you don't find one.  There is only one velocity in your setup.

Comment: Garyp, maybe I'm not so much "misunderstanding" the principle as I am asking about what physical meaning it has.  What good is an "answer" that has no rational basis to justify it?

Comment: If I asked you who is taller, Jim or John, I would expect your response to be along the lines of "Who knows?  More information is needed for me to answer that question."  If, instead, you answered that Jim (or John) is taller, I would question your reason for coming up with that answer.

Comment: @Jack ask Galileo, he proposed the principle of Relativity about 500 years ago. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship#The_proposal

Comment: @m4r35n357:  But Galileo did NOT propose that all frames are "equally valid" and/or that absolute motion cannot be detected.   On the contrary, he insisted the the earth "really does" orbit the sun, rather than vice versa.  When asked the same question, Einstein said that the heliocentric and geocentric frames of reference were "equally valid in principle."  Absolute motion, a la Galileo, should not be confused with absolute velocity.  Newton and Galileo both agreed that absolute velocity could NOT be determined.

Comment: @Jack the point of Galileo's principle of relativity is exactly that all inertial frames are equivalent, and there is no absolute notion of motion that can be detected.

Comment: The fact that the sun's frame of reference is approximately inertial (a reasonable version of heliocentrism) is completely irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: I don't read Galileo that way.  Granted, he said that absolute velocity can't be detected.  But he didn't say the same  with respect to absolute motion.  In his "parable of the ship" he makes it clear that, once released from his "blind" confines in the cabin, the observer, upon reaching open deck, seeing the billowed sails, the coastline, etc., will then know that he is moving (not the earth while he remains motionless).

Comment: That was actually his whole point, i.e., their are other "clues" from which we can legitimately infer our own motion, apart from the raw sensation of moving.  His point was to demonstrate that the earth can "really" be moving around the sun even though we don't sense it.

Comment: Yes, Galilean relativity is a consequence of the rest of the theory, while Einstein relativity is an explicit axiom of the theory, but mathematically, they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Motion simply means a change of distance over time. If you and I are moving relative to each other at 1m/s that just means the distance between us is changing at that rate. If you want to quantify motion, you need to pick some units of distance and time and you need to pick a reference point to measure the distance from. The principle of relativity says it doesn't matter which reference point you pick, so you can pick one relative to which A is not moving, or one relative to which B is not moving, or any other number of reference points relative to which A and B are moving at different rates.

Because we are humans conditioned to think a certain way from birth, we tend to think of everyday speeds relative to the ground, or to some other substantial object in the background, such as the interior of a ship or a train.

If you and I are standing on a street and I walk away from you, you will say I am moving and you are still, when really you are wizzing through space at thousands of miles per hour relative to some far off galaxy and I am wizzing at a slightly reduced rate.

If you and I stand on a train and I walk away from you at 1m/s you might consider that it is I who is moving while you are still. If the train happens to be travelling at 1m/s in the opposite direction, then I will appear to be still to a person on the adjacent platform and you will be moving.

All of which should serve to show that speed is relative, and you can use any reference frame you like to measure it.

Note that the same cannot be said of acceleration. If after standing together I walk away from you at 1m/s, then it is definitely me who has accelerated. I could if I wished (especially if I were a mathematician) declare myself to be fixed and you to have accelerated, but if I did that I would have to invent all kinds of pseudo forces to account for the fact that the rest of the world, along with you, had accelerated away from me when I started to walk.

So the answer is that you are free to pick any reference frame to apportion the relative speed between A and B. You can say A is fixed and B is moving, or you could pick a reference frame in which they are both moving close to c. Whichever you pick, you should get consistent results from any calculations you perform. What physicists usually do is to pick whichever reference frame simplifies their calculations.

Answer (score -4):

I added the following to my original question:

"Edit: More specifically if I, as observer A in this case, want to calculate whose clock has slowed down, where do I put the ".5c" when it comes to filling in "v" in the Lorentz tranformations? Am I allowed to attribute it all to my own frame, implying that I, and I alone, am moving and that my clock has therefore slowed down, while attributing 0 motion to B, implying that he is at rest? Is that an acceptable option?"

So far, no one has answered that specific question, so I will provide my own answer and everyone can tell me how and why they disagree, if they do.  I certainly expect a lot of disagreement.

No, that is NOT an acceptable option.

Why not?

Because that is B's "frame of reference" not yours (you being A).  Inherent it the very definition of a "frame of reference" is that nobody can be moving in their own frame of reference.  In SR, you are not allowed to use someone else's frame of reference to ascertain your OWN motion.

Why not?

Because that would be tantamount to establishing a preferred frame of reference (B's).  That is strictly prohibited in SR.

Why is it prohibited?

Because if you allowed that, the whole SR theory would disintegrate.  In SR each and every observer MUST adamantly and vociferously INSIST that only the other guy is moving, not them.

Take, as an example, a passenger on a moving train.  If that passenger were ever allowed to concede that, relative to the ground, he is moving (not the ground) then he would no longer measure the ("true") speed of light to be c in his frame.  This is because he would also have to then concede that HIS watch has slowed down and that the rods he uses have been distorted by motion.  Using those (speed distorted) measuring instruments might make it "appear" that the speed of light is c in his frame, but he would have to correct for those distortions to arrive at the "true" speed of light in his frame. He would have to take the times and lengths used to make measurements on the ground as the "correct" or valid ones to use in ascertaining the speed of light in his frame.

He would also have to agree with an earth observer about what events are simultaneous.  So "relativity of simultaneity" would also go out the window if he deemed himself to be moving (and the earth not).

Let's face it, no sensible person riding on a train would ever "really" think that he was stationary while the ground (tracks) moved under him and trees, telephone poles, etc. moved past him, rather than vice versa.

But SR relies on, and compels strict compliance with, enforced ignorance.  No observer in SR can ever be aware of his own motion.  He must insist that he is at all times (unless accelerating) "motionless."  In SR, any and every object in the universe which is moving with respect to YOU is deemed to be moving.  YOU are motionless, i.e., your frame of reference is, in effect, the ether frame; the preferred frame.

Every observer in SR must disagree with the claims made by any observer in a different frame of reference.  SR is based on the assertion of contradictory claims.  It must have that conflict to "survive."  And it cannot allow those conflicts to be resolved by letting any two observers AGREE on the question of "which one of us is moving?"

You simply can't use another's frame of reference to determine your own motion.  As stated, that would be tantamount to establishing a preferred frame.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132909/discussion-on-answer-by-jack-how-is-the-relative-speed-of-two-or-more-objects).